# Change and ungroup file icons in Windows 10 (to match icons in Atom/Sublime/VScode)

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, icons, file-types

There is a popular set of file icons, originally for atom, that I want to use as my windows file icons:

[image]
[From here](https://github.com/file-icons/atom)

I know I can create a `.ico` file with the icons in it, though I don't know a particularly convenient way. (I download the `.svg`, then color it, then save it as `.ico`)

The actual issue I'm having is if I change the icon for a given file, it actually changes the icon for the default program. (If I open `.psd .ico, .jpg, .png` in photoshop, they will have the same icon.)

**How can I change the icon based on the extension alone, and not what is used to open it?**

---

I've noticed photoshop files have several different filetype & icons, while files opened with sublime text all have the same icon.

The photoshop extensions are stored in

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Photoshop.<name>FileType.<#>\
```

and have a registry entry for each type.

The files opened with sublime text are **all** stored in

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\sublime_text.exe\
```

So, I assume if I could make individual registry entries for the files that open with sublime text, I would be able to give them unique icons.

Another difference, in FileTypesMan, is the `User Choice` field is blank for the photoshop files, and is `Applications\sublime_text.exe` for all the sublime text files.

I don't know enough about windows registry to say if changing it in this way is possible.

Comment: Not sure if you can change it without [adjusting the registry](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12383/change-a-file-types-icon-in-windows-7/) the linked article is for Windows 7 but it may apply to Windows 10 also.

Comment: Following that guide gives the same grouping issue. It edits the registry value of the application that opens the file.

Comment: How did you get the svg file of a icon?

Comment: [this repository](https://github.com/file-icons/source) has the svg's for all the icons in the pack.